Where is a good resource on AND-OR-XOR-NOR logic of using `syntax`
I gathered that syntax cluster is good for OR-logic (thru its contains=).
And that syntax match is good for ... ???:

OR-logic via \v(abc|def|ghi) type of regex via syntax match.

Where can I get the AND logic by group-name?
Such as doing 5 different groups (possibly in that order).
Or is this concept of syntax'ing is strictly a daisy-chaining of nextgroup=.

Thanks for your question. It is rather abstract (which I like) but I feel I may not capture your demand precisely enough. Maybe could you illustrate the cases with example and end up with a concrete case that you would like to solve. I believe it will help others to provide the kind of answer you need :-)

I did post two questions but have gone up to 10,000' with the eagles to take a look at the broader approaches taken by the Vim experts and to capture what perspective I should be gaining ... here.

No, it doesn't work like this.
Vim tests possible matches according to the current context. That is, topmost level vs. inside of some particular region (or match). On the topmost level it tries every match/region/keyword that is not "contained"; and if inside a region/match, it tests only items that this particular region/match "contains" (or they declare themselves to be "containedin" this region, which is the same thing).
From the paragraph above you can deduce that normal way of defining complex rules in Vim is to create a region within another region within another... and so on. Quite similar to those formal syntax rules.
Clusters are only used to reduce typing (actually, I don't remember the last time I've used them at all).
"Nextgroup" is used to increase match priority when it follows some other match (normal priority rules are documented under :h syn-priority). Also, "nextgroup" has a preference over "contains", "contained" attributes. That is, if match is declared as "nextgroup" then it will be tried first right after the current match is finished (to emphasize the difference: "contains" = "may appear inside me", "nextgroup" = "please, check immediately if it follows me"). But if it doesn't really match then it has no effect.
